# jQuery order by date in data attribute

Tags: jquery

If i have this markup:

```
<p data-date="Fri, 26 Aug 2011 20:58:39 GMT">item 1</p>
<p data-date="Fri, 24 Aug 2011 20:58:39 GMT">item 1</p>
<p data-date="Fri, 25 Aug 2011 20:58:39 GMT">item 1</p>
```

How could i use jQuery to order these P's by their data-date attribute?

Thanks

Comment: ascending or descending?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CQ3gg/2)

Super simple with an array sort:

```
$("p").sort(function(a,b){
    return new Date($(a).attr("data-date")) > new Date($(b).attr("data-date"));
}).each(function(){
    $("body").prepend(this);
})
```

Reverse order (in case I misunderstood you) is as easy as flipping the greater than symbol

```
$("p").sort(function(a,b){
    return new Date($(a).attr("data-date")) < new Date($(b).attr("data-date"));
}).each(function(){
    $("body").prepend(this);
})
```

Comment: lol thanks, @AlienWebguy :) but whatever works works and you had your solution faster anyhow :P

Comment: This method does not appear to work in IE9. Not sure if its .sort in general but the list just reverses in IE9.

Comment: @trobbins26 I don't have IE in front of me right now.  Could you try this updated version? http://jsfiddle.net/CQ3gg/440/

Answer (score 3):

```
function sortDates(a, b)
{
    return new Date(b).getTime() - new Date(a).getTime();
}

var dates = [];
var _old;

$('p').each(function(){
    _old = $(this).parent();
    dates.push($(this).data('date'));
});

var sorted = dates.sort(sortDates);
var _new = $('<div/>').insertBefore(_old);

$.each(sorted,function(i,val){
    $('p[data-date="' + val + '"]').appendTo(_new);
});

_old.remove();
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/JhgSw/

Answer (score 3):

The custom function suggested in Joseph's answer (the currently accepted solution) should return a numeric value, not a boolean. See [This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949951/jquery-javascript-custom-sort-procedure-works-in-firefox-but-ie-doesnt-seem-to) where this issue has already been raised showing that this function will not work in IE.

The "dates.compare(a,b)" function defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-dates-with-javascript) looks like a better fit for use in jQuery's sort method.