# how do I sort li tag using ul tag in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, html-lists

```
<ul id ="sort">
    <li id = '2014-02-07'>tralala<li>
    <li id = '2013-02-09'>tralala<li>
    <li id = '2014-01-04'>tralala<li>
    <li id = '2011-09-05'>tralala<li>
</ul>
```

I want that the result to be :

```
<ul id ="sort">
    <li id = '2014-02-07'>tralala<li>
    <li id = '2014-01-04'>tralala<li>
    <li id = '2013-02-09'>tralala<li>
    <li id = '2011-09-05'>tralala<li>
</ul>
```

I want to sort desc the li using the id in JQuery or Javascript . Thx

Comment: You can also take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7211704/jquery-order-by-date-in-data-attribute

Comment: @omriAharon I want sort after id , not after the value of li

Comment: What is your format currently? YYYY-MM-DD or YYYY-DD-MM?

Comment: @OmriAharon Seems that jQuery `.sort()` is not available anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this :

```
var list = $('#sort'),
    items = list.children().get();
list.append(items.sort(function(a, b){
    return new Date(b.id) - new Date(a.id);
}));
```

Here is a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/wared/EE5HB/.

Comment: thx, it works, but I have a question what happens if my id format is like this : 2008-01-16 18:00:03

Comment: It depends on whether it's supported by the parser : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse.

Comment: @Chester You can reliably parse it by yourself : `var bits = '2008-01-16 18:00:03'.match(/\d+/g); var date = new Date(bits[0], bits[1] - 1, bits[2], bits[3], bits[4], bits[5]);`. Ref : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date.

Comment: @user1636522  For Date sort its working good. In my casse data-recordno only <li data-recordno="80">hi1</li><li data-recordno="79">hi2</li>, What to do?