# sort() function in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

So this code doesnt seem to work with IE, I have not found anything that says it shouldn't.
What am I doing wrong?

```
 ​<ul id="cars">
    <li id="2">Ford</li>
    <li id="1">Volvo</li>
    <li id="3">Fiat</li>
    </ul>



var list = $('#cars').children('li');
    list.sort(function(a,b){
        return parseInt(a.id) < parseInt(b.id);
    });
    $('#cars').append(list);
```

​

Comment: That's a jQuery function -- have you included the jQuery library, at least version 1.3.2?

Comment: Are you saying it works in other browsers?

Comment: @Cory Nope, it's not. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: Incidentally, IDs shouldn't begin with a number. Most browsers are relaxed about this, and HTML5 allows it, but it's still not a good habit. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Comment: Isn't that documented? I can't find anything: http://api.jquery.com/?s=sort

Comment: have a look at [jQuery javascript custom sort procedure works in Firefox, but IE doesn't seem to get it… ][1]. Should give you an idea.

HTH,
--hennson


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949951/jquery-javascript-custom-sort-procedure-works-in-firefox-but-ie-doesnt-seem-to

Comment: have a look at [jQuery javascript custom sort procedure works in Firefox, but IE doesn't seem to get it… ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949951/jquery-javascript-custom-sort-procedure-works-in-firefox-but-ie-doesnt-seem-to) This sould give you an idea of how to do it. HTH, --hennson

Answer (score 7):

The sort function you pass in should return either a number less than zero (a comes before b), 0 (a and b are equivalent) or greater than 0 (a comes after b).

If you just do this, it should work:

```
return parseInt(a.id) - parseInt(b.id);
```

also can't hurt to pass in the radix argument to parseInt, it's a bit safer:

```
return parseInt(a.id, 10) - parseInt(b.id, 10);
```

Comment: Always always pass in the radix argument to parseInt. Better safe than sorry.

Comment: Always pass in the radix!  If you need any reason to do so, just try `parseInt("09")`

Comment: I think you need to process b-a, not a-b.

Comment: @mblase75 -- it's actually a-b (assuming the OP wanted ascending sort), as this fiddle shows: http://jsfiddle.net/MZKcM/  but I can never remember how -1,0,1 sorters work and always have to quickly try an example :)

Comment: @MattGreer Ah, I see -- the OP's IDs aren't in the same order as the names.

Comment: @mblase75 It really could be either, just depends on what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 2):

It's considered incorrect in HTML4 to start IDs with numbers. This rarely causes problems in browsers, but it's also easily avoided.

I replaced your IDs with `data-` attributes, which are automatically extracted by the `.data()` method in jQuery and converted into numbers, eliminating the need for `parseInt`.

HTML:

```
<ul id="cars">
    <li data-val="2">Ford</li>
    <li data-val="1">Volvo</li>
    <li data-val="3">Fiat</li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$('#cars').children('li').sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).data('val')-$(b).data('val');
}).appendTo('#cars');​​​​​
​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qaytJ/1/

`data-` attributes are useful whenever you want to attach arbitrary data to HTML elements, and it's more "correct", or at least more appropriate, than forcing `id` or `class` to do a job it wasn't intended to do. Use them often.