# jQuery sort not working in any IE browser

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, sorting

I'm about to pull my hair out, because of all the extra time spend on nursing IE -_-

Well, I have an unordered list of divs, which I'm trying to sort.
This works perfectly in both Chrome and Firefox, but not IE.

The JS is fairly simple:

```
$('#VariantContainer > .ProductVariant').sort(function(a,b){
 return a.id > b.id
}).appendTo('#VariantContainer')
```

Check out this fiddle in IE:
http://jsfiddle.net/PAJ3w/

Anyone got a clue why?

Thanks :)

BR
Martin

Comment: Take a look on this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949951/jquery-javascript-custom-sort-procedure-works-in-firefox-but-ie-doesnt-seem-to

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery javascript custom sort procedure works in Firefox, but IE doesn't seem to get it... (copy-paste example code)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949951/jquery-javascript-custom-sort-procedure-works-in-firefox-but-ie-doesnt-seem-to)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use number instead of boolean. For me this is the best variant (because it is obvious that we use numbers):

```
parseInt(a.id) - parseInt(b.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  //Order variants
  $('#VariantContainer > .ProductVariant').sort(function(a,b){
        return a.id - b.id;
    }).appendTo('#VariantContainer');
  });
```

Boolean isn't the correct return type and doesn't account for equal values.

Answer (score -2):

I think you're missing the semicolon on the line:

```
return a.id > b.id
```

Firefox and chrome can ignore those little things, but IE can't.
It should be

```
return a.id > b.id;
```

You are declaring a function, therefore it follows all regular rules.