# jquery sort by id element (IE bug)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, sorting

Internet Explorer makes me crazy. Why won't this script work on IE?:
http://jsfiddle.net/THMu3/

HTML:

```
<ul id="cat">
<li id="3">Text 3</li>
<li id="1">Text 1</li>
<li id="2">Text 2</li>
```

JS:

```
$("#cat li").sort(function (a, b) {
return parseInt(a.id) > parseInt(b.id);}).each(function(){
var elem = $(this);
elem.remove();
$(elem).appendTo("#cat");})
```

Comment: what do you mean it does not work? I got the same output in FF and IE

Comment: Wait, why does the fiddle have completely different code? What version of IE? And there is no need to use `elem.remove()` when you use `appendTo()` on the next line.

Comment: IE 11, Have 3-1-2 in output...  http://i.imgur.com/ch6Oxik.png
@Mottie , my bad, edited ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is very simple actually. Change this

```
return parseInt(a.id) > parseInt(b.id)
```

to this

```
return parseInt(a.id) - parseInt(b.id)
```

Check here for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/949970/1845408