# jQuery sorting fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following html structur (endless):

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="content"> Its block 3
      <div class="number">3</div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="content"> Its block 2
      <div class="number">2</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to sort it by clicking a button like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="content"> Its block 2  <--- new order
      <div class="number">2</div> <--- new order
   </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="content"> Its block 3  <--- new order
      <div class="number">3</div> <--- new order
   </div>
</div>
```

... but with my script it doesn´t work (because of the same div class name, I think?). So, how can I sort this and toggle the sort by highest number and lowest number? Can anybody help me?

```
function sortHigh(a, b) {
    var date1 = $(a).find(".content .number").text()
    var date2 = $(b).find(".content .number").text();

    return $(a).find(".content .number").text() > $(b).find(".content .number").text();
};

function sortLow(a, b) {
    var date1 = $(a).find(".content .number").text()
    var date2 = $(b).find(".content .number").text();

    return $(a).find(".content .number").text() < $(b).find(".content .number").text();
};


//how to toggle?
$(function () {
    $('.sort').click(function () {
        $('.content').sort(sortHigh).appendTo('.wrapper');
    }, function () {
        $('.content').sort(sortLow).appendTo('.wrapper');
    });
});
```

Thats my bad try: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o954txn6/)

Comment: *"with my script"* - What script? Please show the relevant code directly in the question, not just via a link to an external site.

Comment: Thats also the problem, I want to sort both, but the sort based on the number. So "Content" and "Number" have to sorting together (they are a group).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to change your code with this:-

```
var toggle="high";
//how to toggle?
$(function(){
 $('.sort').click(function () {
    if (toggle == "high") {            
        toggle = "low";
        $('.list').html($('.list .wrapper').sort(sortLow));
    } else {          
        toggle = "high"
        $('.list').html($('.list .wrapper').sort(sortHigh));
    }
  });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/o954txn6/2/)

Comment: Big thx for support - absolutly what I was looking for!! So my click-action (toggle) was wrong ... good to know.

Comment: @Pepe happy to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues with your code.

The first is that your sorts are sorting strings. `return "2" > "3"` for example.

The other issue is that the click function you're using isn't toggling correctly. I'm guessing you're familiar with the `.hover()` syntax which is why you've done it that way.

As you can see, I'm forcing `sortHigh` and `sortLow` to return Numbers. I've also done a sorting low/high check and toggle within the click function.

```
function sortHigh(a, b) {
    var date1 = Number($(a).find(".number").text());
    var date2 = Number($(b).find(".number").text());

    return date1 > date2;
};

function sortLow(a, b) {
    var date1 = Number($(a).find(".number").text());
    var date2 = Number($(b).find(".number").text());

    return date1 <= date2;
};

$(function(){
    var sortHighCheck = null;

    $('.sort').click(function(){
        if (sortHighCheck === true) {
            $('.wrapper').sort(sortLow).appendTo('.list')
            sortHighCheck = false;
        } else {
            $('.wrapper').sort(sortHigh).appendTo('.list')
            sortHighCheck = true;
        }
    });
});
```

Edit: Forgot to add the [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/o954txn6/6/)

Comment: Also thx for support and explanation! I will test your way too. ... UPDATE: I´ve test it now, maybe I do something wrong, but it doesnt work for me.

Comment: Thx for the link - I see, that you edit the html structur. Thats the problem in my case, the structur cant be modified.

Comment: I've fixed the jsfiddle so it has your structure: http://jsfiddle.net/o954txn6/6/

All it requires is moving everything one level up, sort the `.wrapper` and append to `.list`

Comment: Thx for the update, now it works like charm - great support!!

Comment: I found one bug, the script doesnt work at the IE ;( - why?

Comment: The jsfiddle is running jQuery > 2.0 which doesn't support IE7 or 8. Try changing the version to 1.11 - http://jsfiddle.net/o954txn6/7/

Comment: That also doesn´t work for me and I am using for testing IE 9 & 10. Have you a mac? I use a pc.

Comment: Yeah I'm on a Mac. I suggest you add `console.log()`s at the beginning and end of the various functions to see where exactly it breaks.

Comment: Ok, now the console.log() and all various functions works, but the script is still broken ;(.

Comment: I found the solution. Its "date1 - date2" instead of "date1 < date2" aso. I´ve got it from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949951/jquery-javascript-custom-sort-procedure-works-in-firefox-but-ie-doesnt-seem-to

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery, you can add the sort functionality as such:

```js
jQuery.fn.sortDomElements = (function() {
  return function(comparator) {
    return Array.prototype.sort.call(this, comparator).each(function(i) {
      this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
    });
  };
})();

var srtdesc = true;

$(function() {
  $(".sort").click(function() {
    srtdesc = !srtdesc;
    $(".list").children().sortDomElements(function(a, b) {
      if (srtdesc) {
        return Number($(a).find('.number').text()) - Number($(b).find('.number').text());
      } else {
        return Number($(b).find('.number').text()) - Number($(a).find('.number').text());
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="sort">Sort-Button</button>

<div class="list">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">Its block 3
      <div class="number">3</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">Its block 1
      <div class="number">1</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">Its block 2
      <div class="number">2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks interesting - I will test it too. Thx for support!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort, you can add data-val attribute to each content div:

```
<div class="content" data-val="2"> Its block 2  <--- new order
```

and sort each wrapper div with this code:

```
jQuery("#sort").click( function() {
    jQuery('.wrapper').sort(function (a, b) {
        return jQuery(a).find('.content').data('val') - jQuery(b).find('.content').data('val');
    }).each(function (_, container) {
        jQuery(container).parent().append(container);
    });
});
```

Comment: Also thx for support, but in my case I cant add any html attributes.